# Unable to connect to Sauce labs from directline

Tags: direct-line-botframework, saucelabs

We are trying to test an azure bot from inside a sauce labs environment. API calls from inside sauce labs to directline are going fine, but the API calls originating from directline to sauce labs aren't coming through. Is there a config change that can allow this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Sauce Connect, my first two suspicions would be:

1. Network config on the client side (eg, the machine you're running Sauce Connect on) is preventing connections from Direct Line
2. Sauce Connect's SSL Bumping facility is interfering

Number 2 is pretty easy to rule out; Restart Sauce Connect with the additional command-line flag `-B all` to disable SSL bumping.

Number 1 is harder; what kind of errors or malfunction are you seeing?